# GSOUP библиотека: undefined reference to `soap_ssl_client_context'

Tags: c++, c++11

День добры. Я пишу Клиент сервер для SOUP запроса. Мне нужно пройти авторизацию на сервере. Использую ssl: pem ключ, сертификат и пароль p12.
Для реализации авторизации, решил использовать API gsoap.h/cpp библиотеки.
SOAP Запрос я написал, он компилироваться и работает. Но при добавлении
метода soap_ssl_client_context(), soapcpp2.h Возникает ошибка компиляции. g++ Не может найти метод soap_ssl_client_context(). 
Что я делал: 
Использую gsoap-2.8, скачал с официального сайта, собрал по инструкции, Все собралось, тестовые примеры клиент - сервер работают. 
Все не используемые параметры выставляю NULL/nulptr. Файлы   soapcpp2 и wsdl2h, собираю из user/local/lib, все Ок. При сборки добавлял флаг -lgsoapssl++. 
Пример кода:

```
#include "PGUServicesInfoV1SoapBinding.nsmap"
#include "soapPGUServicesInfoV1SoapBindingProxy.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdsoap2.h>
#include "soapH.h"
#include "soapStub.h"

int main() {

struct soap* soap = soap_new();

char* keyPem = "key.pem";
char* keyP12 = "testSSLClient";
char* certificatePem = "keyStore.WjKbUeCT.pem";

if(soap_ssl_client_context(soap, SOAP_SSL_DEFAULT |  

> **Цитата**

SOAP_SSL_SKIP_HOST_CHECK | 
SOAP_SSL_NO_DEFAULT_CA_PATH, keyPem, keyP12, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr)) {

    soap_print_fault(soap, stderr);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

return 0;

}
```

Спасибо

Comment: явно проблема в линковке - либо библиотеку неверно указываете, либо функции с такой сигнатурой там нет

Comment: Когда  я указываю флаг -lgsoapssl++, ошибка извещает, но появляются другие:    usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsoapssl++.so: undefined reference to `soap_putheader'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsoapssl++.so: undefined reference to `soap_serializeheader'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsoapssl++.so: undefined reference to `soap_faultstring'

Comment: Когда я добавил флаг

Comment: В интернете нет информации как исправить похожие ошибки с gsoap

Comment: так, погодите, так вы еще и без линковки библиотеки собирали? Сударь, вам следет почитать об этапах сборки программы. Ну а ошибка у вас в том, что вы не ликуете все необходимые библиотеки - не удивительно что у вас сыпяться ошибки